# bitbucket.org branch permission on project

Tags: bitbucket

I'm trying to create branch permissions on my project in bitbucket.org. From manual (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html) I can see that there is option to set branch permissions on project level, hwever I can only find a way to do it on repository level.
On project settings page, I cannot find option to setup branch permissions. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: The Bitbucket Server docs you linked do not apply to Bitbucket Cloud. BB Server is the self-hosted version; BB Cloud is bitbucket.org.

Answer (score -2):

This would be helpful to you.

https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/

Comment: I saw this post. It says
"Branch permissions are set on a per-repository basis"
So I guess this is answer for my question...